# Trajectories of predator prey equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am studying the predator prey equation recently, and here is an example:

Let $x'=x(1-0.5y)$ and $y'=y(-0.75+0.25x)$. This is a predator prey equations.
Then $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y'}{x'}=\frac{y(-0.75+0.25x)}{x(1-0.5y)}$$

This is an exact equation and can be easily solved. It follows that 
$$0.75\ln x+\ln y-0.5y-0.25x=c$$

where $c$ is a constant.

Then my book says 'it can be shown that this is a closed curve'. I don't think it is obvious and can anybody tell me why it is closed?

Comment: Let $L(x,y)=3\ln x+4\ln y-2y-x$. The ray issued from the stable point $(3,2)$ in the direction $(u,v)\ne(0,0)$ is $(x(t),y(t))=(3+tu,2+tv)$ with $t>0$. Let $\ell(t)=L(x(t),y(t))$, then $\ell'(t)=-tu^2/(3+tu)-2tv/(2+tv)<0$ for every $t>0$ such that $x(t)>0$ and $y(t)>0$. That is, $L$ is decreasing along each ray issued from $(3,2)$ in the positive quadrant. Since $L\to-\infty$ at the boundary of the positive quadrant, for every $h<L(3,2)$, each $(u,v)$-ray meets the set $L=h$ exactly once. Further work shows that the value $t_h$ where the ray meets $L=h$ depends continuously on $(u,v)$, QED.